# MongoDB auth error when trying to connect to it

Tags: mongodb

I have tried all the solutions google has to offer and stackoverflow too, any help???

Unable to connect to MongoDB:

> Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on
>   database 'krshop' with username 'admin': auth failed

Answer (score 0):

Do you have run mongod?Is located in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin`